# Lambdifying a Sympy vector

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I am using sympy to do vector calculus computations and I wondered if there's an easy way to numerically evaluate vectorial and dyadic expressions. I know of the `lambdify` function which can be used like this:

```
from sympy.abc import x,lambdify

expr=x**x+1
lambda_expr=lambdify(x,expr)
print(lambda_expr(5.0))
```

Is there a similar functionality for dyadic/vectorial expressions? I tried the following code but it throws a syntax error:

```
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, Del

C=CoordSys3D('C')
nabla=Del()

#define some test vectorial field
B=C.x*C.y*C.z*(C.i+C.j+C.k)

#compute a field and a dyad
nabla_B=nabla.dot(B).doit()
rot_B=nabla.cross(B).doit()

#try to get lambda expressions...
lambda_nablaB=lambdify((C.x,C.y,C.z),nabla_b
lambda_rotB=lambdify((C.x,C.y,C.z),rot_B)
```

Syntax Error:

```
 lambda C.x,C.y,C.z: (C.x*C.y*C.z*C.i + C.x*C.y*C.z*C.j + C.x*C.y*C.z*C.k)
                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I wish to numerically evaluate a field/dyad and get a numpy array.

Comment: "Does not work" is not helpful. Post the traceback

Comment: To just get the numerical evaluation you can use `evalf`: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html

Comment: There isn't really a traceback displayed, just a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an ideal answer, but the following solution seems to work. The function evalsym converts the sympy vector to a numpy vector:

```
C=CoordSys3D('C')

def evalsym(symvec,pos):
    numvec=num.zeros(3)
    numvec[0]=symvec.evalf(subs={C.x:pos[0],C.y:pos[1],C.z:pos[2]}).dot(C.i)
    numvec[1]=symvec.evalf(subs={C.x:pos[0],C.y:pos[1],C.z:pos[2]}).dot(C.i)
    numvec[2]=symvec.evalf(subs={C.x:pos[0],C.y:pos[1],C.z:pos[2]}).dot(C.i)
    return numvec
```